# How do I cancel/delete a Windows Update without installing it? On Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-live

So this is going to sound strange...

I got a popup in my system tray from Windows Update saying updates were available. I clicked on it, and it took me to `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Update\Select updates to install`.

The update it wants me to install is Windows Live Essentials 2011. All this does is give the new version of MSN/Windows Live and all the associated programs. I installed this yesterday, decided I didn't like it, and uninstalled it.

Is there any way to delete/block/etc the update, so it will stop telling me to install it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to delete/block/etc the update, so it will stop telling me to install it?

Right click on it, use the context menu to select the option you want.

Comment: To add detail for anyone else wondering: The option on the dropdown menu is called 'Hide' rather than delete, which was what I was looking for.